# Error when launching a new rails app in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a new rails app on Ubuntu 14.04. This is my first time using Rails in Ubuntu, (previously developed in Windows 10). I set up the development environment, my ruby version is ruby `2.3.0p0` and rails version is `5.0.0`. Once my dev environment was set up, I started a new project by typing in a terminal:

```
rails new MyApp
```

Then, I typed:

```
cd MyApp
bundle install
```

And finally, I attempted to start my rails server by typing:

```
rails s
```

Instead of the rails server starting, I get this response in the terminal:

```
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:89:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/home/rusty/Maple/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusty/Maple/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/rusty/Maple/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rusty/Maple/bin/spring:13:in `require'
/home/rusty/Maple/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
    from /home/rusty/Maple/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rusty/Maple/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/rusty/Maple/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/rusty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rusty/Maple/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /home/rusty/Maple/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

My app was created successfully. All the appropriate files are located in my app's folder. I just can't seem to get the rails server to start.

Comment: try to install nodejs

Comment: you are missing javascript engine, try to install v8 or node.js. or use the rubyracer gem inside your gemfile and install it.

Comment: uDay, how do I make you the correct answer? Rails server works now after I installed rubyracer by typing in a terminal/MyApp 'gem install therubyracer' and added 'gem 'therubyracer' to my gemfile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Open a terminal and change to your app's directory. Example, type `cd MyApp`.

Then install the Rubyracer gem by typing `gem install therubyracer` in your terminal, and then add `gem 'therubyracer'` to your gemfile.

My rails server starts now. Thank you uDaY for helping me.